# How to use Vuex store in a plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a custom Vue plugin which has a custom instance method

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Vue from 'vue';
import config from '@/config';

const echor = {
    install(Vue){
        Vue.prototype.$echo = options => {
            return new Echo({
                // how can I get store value inside an instance methods?
                auth: {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `${store.state.auth.token.token_type} ${store.state.auth.token.access_token}`
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

Vue.use(echor);
```

How can I get store value inside an instance methods to make `Authorization` header works? I googled, but nothings help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional argument for the store to your plugin's `install` method:

```js
install(Vue, store){
...
}
```

A consumer of your plugin will call your plugin like:

```js
import echor from '@/echor';  // or however you distribute it
import store from '@/store';  // user's own store

Vue.use(echor, store);
```

You can add any number of additional arguments this way to your install function.